# FacebookSDK Login: Unable to retrieve user profile

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I has successfully import and integrate Facebook latest iOS SDK, login is working fine but whenever I trying to retrieve user profile, it return only admin profile info which is in my developer portal.

My app overview has already cofigure as public, is there anything i needed to configure in order to retrieve user public profile?

this is my login code and retrieving the public profile:

```
[login setLoginBehavior:FBSDKLoginBehaviorNative];
    [FBSDKProfile enableUpdatesOnAccessTokenChange:YES];

    [login logInWithReadPermissions: @[@"public_profile", @"email"] fromViewController:nil handler:^(FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult *result, NSError *error) {
         if (error) {
             NSLog(@"Process error");
         } else if (result.isCancelled) {
             NSLog(@"Cancelled");
         } else {
             [[[FBSDKGraphRequest alloc] initWithGraphPath:@"me" parameters:@{@"fields": @"email"}] startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBSDKGraphRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {
                 if (!error) {

                     NSLog(@"email is %@", [result objectForKey:@"email"]);


                 }
             }];

             NSLog(@"Logged in");
             NSLog(@"%@", [FBSDKProfile currentProfile].userID);
         }
     }];
```

The returning email is my admin email not the user who has logon.

Your effort will be much appreciate. Thank you.

Comment: the native mode will get the user profil that is installed in the facebook app in your device. Try other modes like web and see if it is still giving you the admin account.

Comment: Yes i am using different accounts for my facebook app, and all of those account got my admin profile instead of the individual profile

Comment: Try Web behaviour instead of native behaviour.

Comment: Yes Web behaviour can get my app to obtain other accounts profile, but it wont retrieve the login detail from the facebook app, I must re-enter again the facebook username and password in order to login

Comment: @TejaNandamuri is it the latest facebook SDK no longer support appauth in ios?